# systemd service asks for gpg password in Unity

Tags: unity, gnupg, systemd

I have some systemd-timers to sync my mails via imap. Since I don't want to store my passwords in clear text I use gpg to encrypt and decrypt them.
When I am using Unity each time the timers run the appropriate service an "Access prompt" window pops up and asks for the password of my key.

When I run i3wm and not Unity the timers are working as expected. What might be the problem?